# NullPointerException after updating OneToOne

Tags: hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate and I am dealing with this frustrating issue. I have two classes: `Location` and `Address`. `Address` is an entity and has a foreign key to `Location` primary key. So here's `Location`

```
public class Location implements Serializable {
//Rest of code omitted
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "location", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

and `Address`

```
public class Address implements Serializable {
    //Rest of code ommitted
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "LOCATION_FK")
    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to  update the address of the location object but it's not happening I guess.

```
public void updateAddress(Location location, Address address) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    tx.begin();
    Location persistedLocation = (Location) session.get(Location.class, location.getId());
    Address persistedAddress = persistedLocation.getAddress();
    session.delete(persistedAddress);
    persistedLocation.setAddress(address);
    tx.commit();

    session.close();
}
```

Here's my unit test

```
//Setting variables 
Location location = new Location(); 
Address address = new Address("123456", "TOWN", "CITY", 12345); 
LocationDAO instance = new LocationDAO();

//Add the first location
boolean result = instance.addLocation(location, address);
assertTrue(result); 

//Get it back from database
Location persistedLocation = instance.getLocations().get(0); 
assertEquals(location.getAddress().getAddressLine(), persistedLocation.getAddress().getAddressLine());

Address newAddress = new Address("987654321", "Chicago", "IL", 11234); 

instance.updateAddress(persistedLocation, newAddress);
persistedLocation = instance.getRentalLocations().get(0); 

//Fails on the line below
//assertEquals(newAddress.getAddressLine(), persistedLocation.getAddress().getAddressLine());
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you

Comment: The exception stacktrace you're getting could help better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association is "mappedBy" `Address.location`. This means that Hibernate only considers this side of the association (the owner side), and ignores the other side (the inverse side).

But your code only initializes the inverse side, and neglects to initialize the owner side. The association is thus not persisted in the database.

You need this line in your DAO:

```
address.setLocation(persistedLocation);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a feeling this questions gets asked a lot but what about CascadeType.ALL. Shouldn't that detect it automatically ?

Comment: I think that's where I'm confused.

Comment: CascadeType.ALL means that every operation on a location (merge, persist, remove, etc.) will automatically be done on the address as well. You don't make any operation on the location. And even if you did, no operation will automatically initialize a field of your address. You are responsible for that.